# How can I return a string object from function in c++ without receiving a need semicolon compile error?

Tags: c++

When I try to return a string, I receive a compile error saying that I need a semicolon between before my call of "hello()".

My code is as follows (I included the iostream and string headers). Please help me understand the error in this code.

```
std::string hello()
{
   std::string word = "hello world";
   return word;
}

int main()
{
   std::string userWord = "";

   userWord hello();
   std::cout << userWord << std::endl;
   std::cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't it be

```
string userWord = hello();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
userWord = hello();             // assignment
```

Or better,

```
std::string userWord(hello());  // construct userWord to have the right value
```

Comment: Or how about `std::string userWord = hello() ;`

Comment: Thank you. That is correct. It should be: std::string userWord = hello();